# Crop or split an SVG image to smaller parts

Tags: svg, image-processing

I need to programmatically split an SVG image into smaller parts (square tiles) server-side, preferably with either JavaScript, PHP or any command line tool.

The closest I've came is with the command line tool of [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html). It's easy to create a bitmap:

`inkscape input.svg --export-png=output.png --export-area=0:0:100:100`

But Specifying an export area isn't supported for SVG:

`inkscape input.svg --export-plain-svg=output.svg --export-area=0:0:100:100`

How can I do this?

Comment: And those smaller parts are svg elements?

Comment: Rather squares of SVG images. So if an SVG element happen to be on a cutting line, it should be split.

Comment: I still don't know what you need. However please take a look at this pen. May give you some ideas: [Dividing a Large SVG for Printing](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/jKxJz)